# Ez Publish 4.5 is free or is only Enterprise Edition?

Tags: ezpublish

I'm new to Ez Publish. I need to know if the Ez Publish is like Joomla and is completely free or is a commercial open source application. It is possible to use Ez Publish without paying any fees?

PS: I don't know if this is the place to ask this question.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer :
4.5 is the Enterprise Edition of eZ Publish, also called Matterhorn and is not free.

Long answer :
2011.x is the Community Project version and has the same development base because eZ Systems engineers works and commits their work on the same master branch : https://github.com/ezsystems/ezpublish
The versions of the Community Project that you are able to [download](http://share.ez.no/download-develop/downloads) are snapshots taken from the master branch, and packaged using the same continuous integration tools used by eZ Systems for the Enterprise Edition.

The short story : eZ Systems was used to provide consulting and support services aside eZ Publish but to make it more clear for decision takers, this package (software code source & services) is now called Enterprise Edition. Nothing has really changed, only naming convention, and last but not least, innovation and contribution is now more easy than before.

Comment: Is this answer still valid four years after the post? I noticed the github link goes to "ezpublish-legacy."

Answer (score 2):

Free.... 
http://share.ez.no/download-develop/downloads/ez-publish-community-project-4.2011#platform

The Enterprise editions have extra features for remote Enterprise Management ( a charged-for service and official, supported point releases of patches, enhancements, etc. are  more frequent. But the community editions are also frequent but may not yet be fully tested or official.